# How to wait for AsyncTask to finish?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

I have to call server through the API call. My API call is AsyncTask with `doInBackground()` containing server GET. `onPostExecute()` will get result from server and it will return JSON back to my activity.

Problem is, that I'm using this api call inside the method with return parameter.

Some pseudocode here:

```
private fun getDataFromServer(apiParam: Int): ArrayList<Objects> {

var extractedObjects: ArrayList<Objects> = ArrayList()

api.getDataByParameter(apiParam, object: APICallback{

    override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
        errorLog: errorJSON
    }

    override fun onSuccess(resultJSON: JSONObject) {
        extractedObjects = getObjectsFromJSON(resultJSON)
    }

})

return extractedObjects
}
```

Adding my API Call from API class (custom class):

```
fun getDataByParameter(apiParam: Int, callback: APICallback){

        class GetDataAsync(private val dataCallback: APICallback): AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): JSONObject {

                val server = Server.getInstance(context!!)
             return server.doGet(apiURL + apiParam.toString() + "/")
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: JSONObject) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)

                if (result!!.has("data_objects")){
                    dataCallback.onSuccess(result)
                } else {
                    dataCallback.onError(result)
                }
            }
        }

        GetDataAsync(callback).execute()

    }

interface APICallback{
    fun onError(errorJSON:JSONObject)
    fun onSuccess(resultJSON:JSONObject)
}
```

As you can see, I have to extract objects from `JSONObject` and convert it to `ArrayList<Objects>` (sometimes do other stuff like filtering). So what will happen in my program. As I call `getDataFromServer` it will call AsyncTask to my server and after that it will return empty ArrayList. Until result is available in `onSuccess`, method is already over.

So I need to wait for `onSuccess` and also I have to wait for `getObjectsFromJSON()` to be finished. After that I can return my full list of objects.

Is there any way how to achieve this? I cant do synchronous task, because it will fire **NetworkOnMainThreadException**. I have to do it in second thread, but also my main thread has to wait for results.

Comment: If this is your pseudocode, then your real code is super-wrong. This isn't how callbacks work, you can't synchronously return a List from an async call like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to do it in second thread, but also my main thread has to wait for results.

Clearly, these are two contradictory requirements. The point of the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` isn't the "network" part, but the fact that it's a *blocking* network call. You aren't allowed to perform any kind of blocking calls on the UI thread, be it network or anything else.

What you must do is arrange for your splash screen to be removed within the `onPostExecute` call instead of the UI callback method where you show it.

I would highly recommend upgrading your project to Kotlin Coroutines because with them you can avoid all the messy callbacks and write sequential-looking code which nevertheless satisfies the rules of the UI thread. As an outline, this is how your code would look:

```
class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity, CoroutineContext {
    lateinit var masterJob: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + masterJob

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        masterJob = Job()
        this.launch {
            showSplash()
            val result = makeNetworkCall()
            updateState(result)
            hideSplash()
        }
    }

    suspend fun StartActivity.makeNetworkCall() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Server.getInstance(this).doGet(apiURL + apiParam.toString() + "/")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel() // Automatically cancels all child jobs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the network call inside doInBackground().
get the result from onPostExecute() in the Async task.

Comment: That's how it works now in my API call. onPostExecute will return resultJSON to onSuccess in my activity. But my main thread will not wait for it. It will return list before api call is finished which means "onSuccess()" is called like 30ms after "return extractedObjects"

Comment: This is an async API the OP is using, why use `AsyncTask` on top of it? Just handle your result in `onSuccess`, that's what it's meant for. Even better, get on board with Coroutines and make this look like regular blocking code.

Comment: "Just handle your result in onSuccess" - this is fine if you dont need to work with those results immediately after the call, for example if I call results as I load stuff during splash screen. But as I need to work with those data immediately, I need to have them returned. In my program its like this. buttonListener -- click button -- get results from server (async) - do some stuff with them -- return them in proper format -- do other stuff.

Comment: The lifetime of the splash screen isn't confined to the duration of a single method. You can arrange for the splash to disappear in `onSuccess`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you actually cannot guarantee that, only that it is callback-based.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You mean, it could be a callback-based **sync** API? Here's a challenge: find a single public library with that kind of API :)

Comment: Maybe it's not a public library, just a bad implementation :p

Comment: Yes, and in that case I'd recommend fixing that problem at the source.